# UIBarButtonItem with image doesn't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set a `UIBarButtonItem` with an `image`. The problem is that it never appears. When I just add a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `title` it works.

```
UIBarButtonItem *openLeftSliderButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openLeftSlider)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = openLeftSliderButton;
```

Comment: can you please confirm the image name & if it is present in bundle ?

Comment: Oo I feel so stupid right now. The icon had indeed another name. The desinger who added the icons renamed it. Appcode suggested me the name of the file and it just compiled. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AadilKeshwani Make it an answer so it can be checkt as correct.

Comment: how can I make this an answer?

Comment: @dasdom Thanks Its okay i was glad to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIImage *sideImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"i1.jpg"];    
 UIButton *btnSideMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];     
 [btnSideMenu setImage:sideImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 [btnSideMenu setImage:sideImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];  
 [btnSideMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)]; 
 [btnSideMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(btnLeftMenuClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
 UIBarButtonItem *sideMenuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnSideMenu];    
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=sideMenuItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithCustomView`

```
_leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_leftButton sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_leftButton];
```